# Hook into 'when user logs in' [persistent login]

Tags: filters, login, actions

I'm trying to create a persistent login mechanism in Wordpress (I can't find a plugin, but if there is one, let me know!).

But I'm struggling to find a hook (add_action or add_filter) that runs when the user is initially authenticated by wordpress when logging in.

Does anyone know of an appropriate way to execute code only once when a user logs into wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_login` action is available.

> The wp_login action hook is triggered when a user logs in by the wp_signon() function. It is the very last action taken in the function, immediately following the wp_set_auth_cookie() call.

Check this [official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login).

Answer (score -1):

I know it's been a while, but I've since created a plugin to remember users and keep them logged into WordPress (unless they choose to logout).

Just incase anyone else has a similar question.

The plugin is here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-persistent-login/

It does use wp_login at its core, as suggested in the other answer.